# while using JAXB in converting some values does not converting

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Performing the conversion from XML to Java classes using JAXB statement.But I am facing some problems. That is, it can successfully convert the values in the attributes in the XML tag.But I can't translate the xml tag's own values. For example I want to convert this into my java calsses: `<tag>value</tag>`

This is my xml tag line:

```
<element Id="BGM01">220</element>
```

and this is my java classes.

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class element {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    private String Id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Composite")
    private String Composite;
    private List<subelement> subelement;
}
```

when generate java classes from xml file it generates values as like

```
{
                "subelement": null,
                "id": "BGM01",
                "composite": null
}
```

as you can see value of tag **220** are not readed.

What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

To enable a character VALUE (i.e. **220**) to appear within the root element *together with subelements*, its `complexType` must have a *mixed* attribute set to "true".

Create a Maven project named **Element** using the standard file layout. This project includes:

- An XML Schema file [element.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/element/src/main/resources/element.xsd) for the `Element` model
- A JAXB *binding* file [element.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/element/src/main/resources/element.xjb) for customizations
- A JUnit test class to demonstrate (un)marshalling
- Sample XML files with `Element` data.
- The Maven POM file with `hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin`

```
Element
    src
        main
            java
            resources
                element.xjb
                element.xsd
        test
            java
                org/example/element/ElementTest.java
            resources
                simplelogger.properties
            samples
                Element101.xml
                Element102.xml
    pom.xml
```

The JAXB classes are generated by this plugin in this project's [pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/element/project-pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and are generated to:

```
target/generated-sources/xjc/
    org.example.element
        Element.java
        Subelement.java
        ObjectFactory.java
```

##### Model

The model for this example consists of a root element with attributes, child elements and a value.

```
element: root mixed="true"
    Id: attribute
    Composite: attribute
    subelement: children
    VALUE
```

##### Testing

```
mvn clean test
```

This [output](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/element/OUTPUT.txt) shows the test results.

The JUnit test class, [ElementTest](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/element/src/test/java/org/example/element/ElementTest.java), scans for the sample files and invokes the method `checkSample(File sample)` to provide each file to the tester. For this project, a `JAXBContext` is created and each file in the [samples](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/element/src/test/samples) path is *unmarshaled* to an `element` object. When successful, the `element` object is *marshaled* for logging and your review.

> **Note:** For *mixed* content types, JAXB generates a `List` field named `content` to store an array of the sub-elements and value(s) found. There can be multiple values interspersed among the sub-elements. The `List` preserves the order of the sub-elements and values. If white-space is used to format the content, it will be bound to the neighboring values! A better alternative may be to eliminate the need for *mixed* content by declaring individual elements, in the model, for each data value.

##### Download

A zip containing the standalone *Maven* project and source code for this solution can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-element-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip).

##### Java-First Design

In a *Java-First Design* (without xsd), the key to parsing the `220` value is to add a `@XmlMixed` annotation to the `content` field. When unmarshalling, the value will be included in the `content` list.

**Element.java**

```
package org.example.element;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "content" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public class Element implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20230301L;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "subelement", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) { content = new ArrayList<>(); }
        return this.content;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    protected String id;
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String value) { this.id = value; }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Composite")
    protected String composite;
    public String getComposite() { return composite; }
    public void setComposite(String value) { this.composite = value; }
}
```

**Subelement.java**

```
package org.example.element;

import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "subelement")
public class Subelement implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20230301L;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    protected String id;
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String value) { this.id = value; }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Composite")
    protected String composite;
    public String getComposite() { return composite; }
    public void setComposite(String value) { this.composite = value; }
}
```

Comment: No I don't need to create xsd file